# How to deploy javafx application with sqlite?

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, netbeans, inno-setup

I'm working on a JavaFX application that contains a SQLite database named-"CSRM.db".I'm using netbeans and trying to deploy this project into .exe installer with inno setup environment. My sqlite connection script looks like this:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:CSRM.db");
```

BTW, after successfully installing the application it can't access the - CSRM.db . So how can I deploy the application with SQLite ? How to add the SQLite file path for deployment?

I have added these extra lines for deployment(netbeans build config), build.xml-

```
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy">
<fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}"
 nativeBundles="all"
 outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">
<fx:application name="${application.title}" mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>
<fx:resources>
<fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
 <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="lib/*.jar"/>
</fx:resources>
<fx:info title="${application.title}" vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
</fx:deploy>
</target>
```

Comment: `CSRM.db` is a relative file name.  You have no control over the current directory when other people run your application, so a relative file name is never going to be reliable.  If you know the exact absolute path to which you’ve installed the database file, pass that in your JDBC URL.  Otherwise, copy it to a known location (like a [temporary file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29)) and pass that absolute path in the URL.

Comment: @VGR To copy a file, you still need its exact path. So the second part of your comment won't help, imo.

Comment: I package my files in the `jar` When the program first runs, I check for the files. If those files are not in the same folder as my `jar`, I extract them from the `jar` and add them to the directory.